# Loading Grid using coroutines - wait until finish,

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

One of the scripts on my scene involves creating a grid of cubes. The process does take a fair amount of time and I've been trying to implement it without causing Unity to become unresponsive.

The code at present - works to effect - you can watch as the grid is generated. However, the other scripts in the scene are doing their tasks at the same time and is causing exceptions (they're accessing tiles on the grid which are not yet created).

The script below is the only script that has an 'Awake' function - the other scripts are executing 'Update' and 'OnGUI' before the first script has finished its awake.

```
 GridGenerator.cs

public GameObject[,] tiles = new GameObject[Constants.BOARD_WIDTH, Constants.BOARD_HEIGHT]; 
   // Run a double loop to create each tile.
    void Awake () 
    {
        StartCoroutine(doSetup());
    }

    IEnumerator doSetup()
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine (loadLevel());
        DoOtherStuff();
    }

    IEnumerator loadLevel()
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < Constants.BOARD_WIDTH; i++)             
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Constants.BOARD_HEIGHT; j++) 
            {
                tiles[i,j] = newTile();
                yield return(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I make the doOtherStuff() method wait until the co-routine is finished?

I've tried a boolean toggle (which froze unity)
I've tried using lock (which didn't work)

Or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

EDIT: The code successfully completes OtherStuff() after the the grid is generated. Apart of the doOtherStuff() is to pass a reference of the grid to a separate class. 
The separate class is throwing exceptions when trying to access the grid in the Update method. Which suggests, the update method is being called before the Awake in the GridGenerator.cs is completed.

Comment: so the other things are looking for the tiles, is there a way that when they're looking for them they can tell whether or not they've been generated and are available yet? might need to provide more code that's showing how the tiles are being stored / accessed by the other routines

Comment: Yes, that's a solution - checking to ensuring the tiles are generated first. But will involve adding extra conditions to all places that require the tiles...

Ah, the tiles are stored in a multi-dimensional array of GameObjects. Updated the main post - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to kick off your coroutine within another coroutine, so that you can yield to it:

```
void Awake () 
{
    StartCoroutine(doSetup());
}

IEnumerator doSetup ()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(createGrid()); // will yield until createGrid is finished
    doOtherStuff();   
}

IEnumerator createGrid()
{   
        for (int i = 0; i < Constants.BOARD_WIDTH; i++)             
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Constants.BOARD_HEIGHT; j++) 
            {
                // Instantiate a new tile 
                yield return(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response and this works to some degree
Ignoring the log, it works fine and the grid is generated.
However, it is still exiting the Awake function before the grid is being generated and as a result some other scripts are logging exceptions

It's vastly better than how it was (as before it was crashing mid way through generating the grid). Any ideas on how to stop it exiting the awake method until the grid is finished?

Comment: The `Awake` method cannot be a coroutine, and so can't yield to another coroutine. You'll either have to refactor to handle asynchronous grid creation, or just do it synchronously.